# Rutas Laravel 6, problema al formar una URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Estoy buscando la manera de personalizar mis URL, con Laravel 6, me vale, pero necesito añadir en las rutas unos textos y estos que sean dinámicas según, según el valor enviado desde una vista.

Pongo el código de mis routes/web.php de Laravel 6, funciona peri necesito que sea de otra manera las URLs, os pongo ejemplos y código:

Este código me funciona bien, me genera la URL **dominio.com/mantenimiento-calderas/poblacion**
  routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/mantenimiento/{population}', 'FrontController@oferta');
```

Yo necesitaria que la url fuera **dominio.com/mantenimiento-poblacion**.

He intentado pasarlo, de la siguiente manera, pero no me funciona me da error de indice 0

```
Route::get('/mantenimiento-{population}', 'FrontController@oferta');
```

Controller:

```
public function ofertas($population)
{
    return view('oferta', $population);
}
```

Me devuelve, este error:

> ErrorException Undefined offset: 0
>   http://cptoledo.test/mantenimiento-alcabon

¿Hay alguna manera de formar la URL como necesito o con Laravel 6 , no se puede?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola mi código estaba lleno de fallos, mezclaba plural con singular y el `return()` a la vista esta mal, para que esto funcione bien debería ser así:

Route  web.php

```
Route::get('/mantenimiento-{population}', 'FrontController@oferta');
```

Controller

```
public function oferta($population)
{
    return view('oferta')->with('population', $population);
}
```

Comment: No olvides marcar como aceptada tu respuesta si es la solución a tu problema